# Как сделать из проекта на питоне exe файл

Tags: python, exe, сборка

Нужно из файлов, собранных в [данном репозитории](https://github.com/Dmitry-Mihajlov/Russion_language_application) собрать `exe` файл.

Сам как только не пробовал, ничего нормально не получалось

Comment: Напишите что конкретно не получается. Вы в комментарии к ответу пишите про антивирус, а в вопросе про это ничего нет - про это догадаться нужно было?

Comment: А другие все ответы на сайте читали про конвертацию питона в exe? Тут их очень много было.

Answer (score 1):

Одним из удобных и простых способов скомпилировать ваш python код - это использование auto-py-to-exe. Вот как его установить.

**Пишем в терминале:**

1. Устанавливаем

`pip install auto-py-to-exe`

2. Переходим в папку

`cd auto-py-to-exe`

3. Запускаем файл

`python setup.py install`

4. Открываем программу

`auto-py-to-exe`

Если вы сделаете всё верно, то вы откроете удобное приложение  с графическим интерфейсом. Рекомендую сразу поставить русский язык и далее указываете путь к программе и выбираете другие параметры, исходя из ваших целей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все равно не выходит, если использовать pyinstaller, то антивирусник сразу удаляет exe и распознает его как вирус, а py-to-exe просто не заканчивает ни как сборку

Comment: тогда добавьте программу в исключения,  либо отключите антивирус.